# Python: subscriptable class

Tags: design-patterns, python-3.x, metaclass

My `class Item` describes certain items, which are naturally known by their numeric ID (0, 1, 2, ...). I have implemented a registry inside the class, which indexes all the objects by their ID. I also have a method that retrieves an object by its ID:

```
class Item
    _registry = []
    def __init__(self):
        self._registry.append(self)
        # ...
    @classmethod
    def get_item_by_id(cls, k):
        return cls._registry[k]
    # ...
```

Is this a reasonable design?

Assuming it is, would it be ok to allow subscripts for the `Item` class itself? I can (I think) define `__getitem__` in `Item`'s metaclass, thus allowing the syntax `Item[2]` instead of `Item.get_item_by_id(2)`.

If it has any problems (e.g., too weird, can cause undesirable side effects, etc), please let me know.

Comment: that's what `__getitem__` is for...

Comment: a nitpick:  I think line 4 should read `self.__class__._registry.append(self)`, which is more explicit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. That's perfectly fine. It's definitely better than the long form. Just make sure you return sensible exceptions (a `KeyError` with a descriptive message, e.g. `Invalid id for element`) when someone uses an incorrect index. Also, make sure that you document this behavior, otherwise there'd be no point in making the object subscriptable in the first place.